# protoc has trouble with input file

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc

I have this shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir_name="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE}")" && PWD)"

protoc --go_out="$dir_name" --go-grpc_out="$dir_name" "${dir_name}/myservice.proto"
```

I get this strange error message:

```
alex@alex yoda % /Users/alex/codes/yoda/yoda.ores.int/src/proto/generate.sh
/Users/alex/codes/yoda/yoda.ores.int/src/proto
/Users/alex/codes/yoda/yoda.ores.int/src/proto/myservice.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).
```

here is the error more legibly:

> File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or
> -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file
> names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g.
> absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).

the input file(s), output files, and generate script are all in the same folder.
Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

The single input file currently looks like this:

// myservice.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package myservice;

// Define your gRPC service.
service MyService {
  rpc SendMessage (MessageRequest) returns (MessageResponse);
}

// Define your request and response message types.
message MessageRequest {
  string message_data = 1;
  // Add more fields as needed
}

message MessageResponse {
  string status = 1;
  // Add more fields as needed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`protoc` is challenging with respect to import paths.

Because (!) you reference `myservice.proto` prefixed with `${dir_name}`, you must include `--proto_path=${dir_name}` too:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path="$dir_name" \
--go_out="$dir_name" \
--go-grpc_out="$dir_name" \
"${dir_name}/myservice.proto"
```

Your use of `$dir_name` is unclear to me; generally I'd use `${PWD}`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/myservice.proto
```

If `service.proto` is in the `${PWD}`, you can simplify this (but I prefer the more explicit version above) as:

```bash
protoc \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
myservice.proto
```

Once you remove the `${PWD}` (or equivalent) from `myservice.proto`, you no longer need `--proto_path` (in this case).

However (!) ...

`myservice.proto` is defined to be within a `package`, specifically `package myservice`. It's curious that it's not enforced but the convention is to represent protobuf (!) `package` hierarchies as folders (under `proto_path` roots), i.e.:

```
${PWD}
└── myservice
    └── myservice.proto
```

You can see this in Google's Well-Known Types usually distributed with `protoc` in the `include` folder:

```
.
└── google
    └── protobuf
        ├── any.proto
        ├── api.proto
        ├── compiler
        │   └── plugin.proto
        ├── descriptor.proto
        ├── duration.proto
        ├── empty.proto
        ├── field_mask.proto
        ├── source_context.proto
        ├── struct.proto
        ├── timestamp.proto
        ├── type.proto
        └── wrappers.proto
```

If pick any of these, e.g. `timestamp.proto`, you'll see that its package is `google.protobuf` and it's represented in the `include` folder as `google/protobuf/timestamp.proto`.

Using this convention, your command would be:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/myservice/myservice.proto
```

And, lastly, Go is going to moan about being "unable to determine Go import path".

There are actually different ways to do this.

Commonly you'll see `--go_opt=paths=source_relative` but my preference is to use `--go_opt=module=${MODULE}` as follows:

> **NOTE** You'll need to add both `--go_opt` and `go_grpc_opt` flags.

Assuming:

```bash
MODULE="github.com/foo/bar"

go mod init ${MODULE}

# This is the protobuf root folder
mkdir protos
```

And:

```
.
├── go.mod
└── protos
    └── myservice
        └── myservice.proto
```

Then update `myservice.proto` to include the value (!) of:

```protobuf
option go_package = "${MODULE}/protos";
```

And:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--go_out=${PWD} \
--go_opt=module=${MODULE} \
--go-grpc_out=${PWD} \
--go-grpc_opt=module=${MODULE} \
${PWD}/protos/myservice/myservice.proto
```

Yielding:

```
.
├── go.mod
└── protos
    ├── myservice
    │   └── myservice.proto
    ├── myservice_grpc.pb.go
    └── myservice.pb.go
```